# Pandas expandable data structure - minimize memory consumption

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, memory-optimization

this may seem like a duplicate question to many of you, but I could not find a satisfactory answer.

I have a TimeSeries data object to which I append data worst case every 200ms. 
Now, this is very very memory heavy as I understand it has to re-create the underlying data structures again and it does not seem to be cleaning up the old objects. 
I tried something like

```
old = mydata 
mydata = mydata.append(...)
del old
```

which did not make any difference at all!

The problem is that my process works on a host with only 1GB of memory and this kind of processing
exhausts the host memory rather quickly.

I need the to keep at least the last 30ish hours worth of data in memory as analytics are performed every 200ms/every tick.

Any suggestions to optimize memory - and still keep the pandas.TimeSeries functionality (slicing based on time intervals).

Comment: Well `append` is a wrapper for `concat` so if you can use an implementation using `concat` it should be marginally faster.

Comment: I am not too worried about speed, but memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

An `append` operation returns a new Series. So you are copying the data each time which is quite inefficient (from speed and memory perspective). The usual way to deal with this is to pre-create a larger size than needed then simply fill in the values. Resizing periodcially if needed. (this is how python lists/dict do it as well).

I give an example [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2801), as well as a way to use `HDFStore` to do this.

```
In [7]: df = DataFrame(index=range(5),columns=list('AB'))

In [8]: df.iloc[0] = Series(dict(A = 10, B = 5))

In [9]: df.iloc[1] = Series(dict(A = 11, B = 6))

In [10]: def f(x,indexer):
   ....:     return x.iloc[0:indexer]*2
   ....: 

In [11]: f(df,2)
Out[11]: 
    A   B
0  20  10
1  22  12

In [12]: df.iloc[2] = Series(dict(A = 12, B = 7))

In [13]: f(df,3)
Out[13]: 
    A   B
0  20  10
1  22  12
2  24  14
```

Comment: this is great, but I need the datetime slicing functionality provided by pandas.TimeSeries data type e.g. 
   myTs[datetime1:datetime2]

Comment: so add a DatetimeIndex. ``.iloc`` is a positional indexer to *set* the index, however, you can slice it however you want.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try, however the only problem is that I dont know the indexes before they come in! as my index is a timestamp I dont know them before they arrive, so as they come in I will have to add them to the DataFrame object. Will this result in similar behaviour as with the TimeSeries data type ?

Comment: you are better off just making it a column - when u looking up just do a selection on that column - no advantage of having an index here

Comment: how exactly do you do that ?